# How to combine rows in a data frame with dplyr group by and flatten other data?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data frame:

```
UID               HH0  HH1  HH2  HH3  HH4  HH5
JEZAF000080843824 NA   NA   NA   1    NA   NA
JEZAF000080843824 NA   NA   NA   NA   Y    NA
JEZAF000080843824 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   2
```

Here is what I looking for in the results

```
UID               HH0  HH1  HH2  HH3  HH4  HH5
JEZAF000080843824 NA   NA   NA   1    Y    2
```

I have played around with `dplyr` with `group_by` but I am not sure what function to `%>%` into. I know there is probably a simple answer but I am new with R.

Comment: start with `df %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarise_all(max, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `na.omit`

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(UID) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
# A tibble: 1 × 7
#               UID   HH0   HH1   HH2   HH3   HH4   HH5
#              <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <int> <chr> <int>
#1 JEZAF000080843824    NA    NA    NA     1     Y     2
```

Comment: I think this will work but I am hitting a error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value. The data frame is formatted with column types as Factors. I am wondering if the problem is there.

Comment: @ddamko  In the example you showed, there was only a single non-NA  value per UID.  If that is not the case in original dataset, we have to change it something like HubertL commented